# Alternatives to Hadoop / Map-reduce framework for win32 platform

Tags: python, winapi, dictionary, hadoop, reduce

I'm finding Hadoop on Windows somewhat frustrating: I want to know if there are any serious alternatives to Hadoop for Win32 users. The features I most value are:

- Ease of initial setup & deployment on a smallish network (I'd be astonished if we ever got more than 20 worker-PCs assigned to this project)
- Ease of management - the ideal framework should have web/GUI based administration system so that I do not have to write one myself.
- Something popular & stable. Bonuses depend on us getting this project delivered in time.

**BACKGROUND:**

The company I work for wants to build a new grid system to run some financial calculations.

The first framework I have been evaluating is Hadoop. This seemed to do exactly what was intended except that it's very UNIX oriented. I was able to get all of the tutorials up & running on an Ubuntu VirtualBox. Unfortunately nothing seems to run easily on Win32.

Yes... Win32: Our company has a policy that everything has to run on Windows. None of the server admins (or anybody outside of select few developers) know anything about Linux. I'd probably get in trouble if they found my virtual Ubuntu environment! The sad fact is that our grid needs to be hosted on Win32 (since all the test PCs run Windows XP 32bit), with an option to upgrade to Win64 at sometime in the future.

To complicate matters - 95% of what we want to run are Python scripts with C++ Windows 32bit DLL add ons. Our calculation library is overwhelmingly written in Python. Our calculation libraries will not run on anything other than Windows... I do not really have a choice

Comment: First Google Hit: http://hayesdavis.net/2008/06/14/running-hadoop-on-windows/.  What's wrong with this?  Do you need more information?  Different information?

Comment: Yes, I've been using that guide already. The article was written in 2008. It's plausible that many things have changed in the last three years.

Comment: I **know** that it's theoretically possible to make it work...  I'm trying to find out if people are actually doing this!

Comment: Google's [AppEngine](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) MapReduce framework may help you.  It allows you to write MapReduce in Python, but hosts the service on their hardware.  Linking with your DLLs may also be problematic, see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#libraries).

Answer (score 2):

For python there is:

- [disco](https://github.com/discoproject/disco)
- [bigtempo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bigtempo)
- [celery](https://github.com/celery/celery/) - not really a map-reduce framework, but it's a good start if you want something very customized

And you can find a bunch of hadoop clients/integrations on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=hadoop&submit=search)

Answer (score 1):

You could try MPI. It is a standard for message-passing concurrent applications. We are running it on our Linux cluster but it is cross-platform. The most popular implementation is [mpich2](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/), written in C. There are python bindings for MPI through the [mpi4py](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/) library.

Comment: is mpich2 / mpi4py an approximate replacement for Hadoop? THis project looks like some profoundly deep computer-science. I'm worried that I might have to invest a whole bunch of time into this project before I manage to get the clustering equivalent of Hello World working!

Comment: you can build mapreduce on top of MPI. Don't know if this is your intent.

Comment: I've never used Hadoop, so I can't say much about it. As far as I can tell, they capture similar functionality but have rather different interfaces.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the documentation. It seems to be a very general purpose framework. It sounds like I'd need to do a lot of wheel-reinvention before I'd get a basic M/R framework running, right?

Comment: Perhaps, MPI is a bit more low-level than Hadoop. It may not be exactly what you are looking for. What was the problem with gettng Hadoop to work on Windows? It is written in Java, so I don't see how things could change so much going across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

IPython has some parallel computing features that are simple and work on windows. It may be enough for your needs. Here's a good place to start:

http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=7200100&fromSeriesID=720

Comment: Unfortuantely my project is stuck on cPython. It's not within my capabilty to change this.

Comment: cPython is implementation of the Python language in C/C++. This has nothing to do with IPython, which is a cPython module.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled a list of available [MapReduce/Hadoop offerings in the cloud](http://webofdata.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/hosted-mapreduce-hadoop/) (hosted services, PaaS-level), this might be of help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Many distributed computing frameworks can be used for **many-task computing**. If you don't need the MapReduce paradigm, but rather the ability to distribute the tasks of a job across separate computers, communication and resource management, then you could take a look at other platforms in this area like [Condor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/), or even [Boinc](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/); both run on Windows.

You could also run Hadoop on Linux virtual machines.